# Sending Fax by RingCentral API

Tags: fax, ringcentral

I was trying to use fax API of RingCentral on Sandbox URL using REST client:

https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/fax 
with following:

```
Authorization: Bearer {{my access_token}}"
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "to": [{
        "phoneNumber": "<my phone number>"
    }],
    "faxResolution": "High",
    "sendTime": "2019-02-20T09:30:10.800Z"
}
```

But getting **Bad Request** issue from the fax API:

```
status code=400 content type=application/json;
{
    "message": "Bad Request",
    "errors": []
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue clearly shows the ***contentType*** or  **fax MIME body**...
Since the fax api support attachments as data. **400 Bad request error** is caused due to wrong content or mime type

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed
```

The API allows sending a fax message with a multipart request, incorporating two or more parts.

ref: https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-reference#

Following reference has described the same:

https://forums.developers.ringcentral.com/questions/517/weird-boundary-in-presence-response-when-requestin.html

https://forums.developers.ringcentral.com/questions/614/switching-to-f-form-option-for-posting-multipartmi.html?page=2&pageSize=10&sort=oldest